# Android sdk. Как поменять путь установки android sdk

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk

Здравствуйте, при установке Android Studio вылезла ошибка: "your sdk location contains non-ascii characters".
Как я понял, ошибка в том, что у меня в пути к android sdk есть русские символы.
Но при установке Android Studio я не нашел, как поменять путь установки android sdk.
Не могли бы вы подсказать мне, как можно поменять этот путь?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я так понимаю вам надо в окне на втором скрине (*SDK Component Setup*) указать путь, вроде *C:\SDK* (внизу поле ввода *Android  SDK Location*, нажмите на три точки справа от него, путь не должен включать не латинские буквы, символы и пробелы), тогда можно будет поставить отметку на пункте *Android SDK* и он установится. Сейчас вы получаете ошибку, что в пути *C:\Program files* есть пробел и он не подходит для установки

Answer (score 3):

File-Settings-Appearance&Behavior-SystemSettings-AndroidSDK

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я поставил путь, например, "C:\Program files, но все равно при нажатие на finish, путь остается пустым. Я добавил еще скрины к вопросу

Comment: Возможно, вы путаете папки со студией и с СДК. Они не входят одна в другую и могут быть в разных местах. Возможно у вас СДК вовсе не скачено.

Comment: Не подскажите, а где его можно скачать отдельно?

Comment: Возможно, в конце страницы то, что вам нужно. Ну или поищите ещё раз в папке со студией. https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Comment: Большое спасибо